# Android Static Fragments - App crash problem

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am an android beginner, just learning android static fragment concept, but after running my code getting app crash issue. Here is details:

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.lalendrakumar.fragmentdemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="2">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

So anyone can solve my problem.

Comment: I can't find any details of the crash currently in your question.

Comment: Update the crash logcat.

Comment: instead of <fragment use FrameLayout and pass your fragment to it. and set height to 0dp

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the two fragments to fill the page. "fill_parent" has been replaced now by "match_parent." However, if you use this, in theory, the two fragments will overlap one over the other.

To split them in the screen, each will have to be adjusted to height zero. This is how each fragment's dimensions should read

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mentioned which layout you are using, but i assume you are using LinearLayout. LinearLayout take orientation horizontal by default, and you gave height and width to match_parent(fill_parent is deprecated now and replaced by match_parent)

Please find more information about LinearLayout on this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout)

Replace your code with following

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try commenting out these lines in fragment class (if they are present )

```
     /*  @Override
       public void onAttach(Context context) {
       if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
          mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
      }
   }
 */
```